# Semantic UI: How is it possible to left align an action item?

Tags: html, css, alignment, semantic-ui

I'm trying to add a *left aligned* `button` to a `Semantic UI` `modal` within the `actions` region, through using a `container` element, and I uploaded a sample [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdty8xf1/5/) in order to give more details about the code:

```
<div id="modal" class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui left aligned container">
    <div class="ui button">
      <i class="eraser icon"></i>
        Clear
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui black deny button">
      Cancel
    </div>
    <div class="ui approve positive right labeled icon button">
      Submit
      <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the container doesn't well apply the alignment: while the button gets left aligned, it loses its `vertical alignment` with other `action items`.

I have not found any method on implementing the alignment, despite having read the Semantic UI documentation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `float: left` on the `left-aligned-container`

```css
.left-aligned-container {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.css">
<div id="modal" class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui left-aligned-container">
      <div class="ui button">
        <i class="eraser icon"></i> Clear
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui black deny button">
      Cancel
    </div>
    <div class="ui approve positive right labeled icon button">
      Submit
      <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('#modal').modal('show')
</script>
```